# Local variable location from DWARF info in ARM

Tags: debugging, gcc, arm, reverse-engineering, dwarf

I have a C program in file `delay.c`:

```
void delay(int num)
{
   volatile int i;
   for(i=0; i<num; i++);
}
```

Then I compile the program with gcc 4.6.3 on ARM emulator (armel, more specifically) with command `gcc -g -O1 -o delay.o delay.c`. The assembly in `delay.o` is:

```
00000000 <delay>:
   0:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
   4:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   8:   e58d3004    str r3, [sp, #4]
   c:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  10:   e1500003    cmp r0, r3
  14:   da000005    ble 30 <delay+0x30>
  18:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  1c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  20:   e58d3004    str r3, [sp, #4]
  24:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  28:   e1530000    cmp r3, r0
  2c:   bafffff9    blt 18 <delay+0x18>
  30:   e28dd008    add sp, sp, #8
  34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I want to figure out where the variable `i` is on the stack of function `delay` from debugging information. Below is the information about `delay` and `i` in `.debug_info` section:

```
<1><25>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
   <26>   DW_AT_external    : 1
   <27>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x19): delay
   <2b>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
   <2c>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
   <2d>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
   <2e>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0
   <32>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x38
   <36>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0      (location list)
   <3a>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x59>
...
<2><4b>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_variable)
   <4c>   DW_AT_name        : i
   <4e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
   <4f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3
   <50>   DW_AT_type        : <0x60>
   <54>   DW_AT_location    : 0x20     (location list)
```

It shows that the location of `i` is in the location list. So I output the location list:

```
Offset   Begin    End      Expression
00000000 00000000 00000004 (DW_OP_breg13 (r13): 0)
00000000 00000004 00000038 (DW_OP_breg13 (r13): 8)
00000000 <End of list>
00000020 0000000c 00000020 (DW_OP_fbreg: -12)
00000020 00000024 00000028 (DW_OP_reg3 (r3))
00000020 00000028 00000038 (DW_OP_fbreg: -12)
00000020 <End of list>
```

From address 4 to 38, the frame base of `delay` should be `r13 + 8`. So from address c to 20 and from address 28 to 38, the location of `i` is `r13 + 8 -12 = r13 - 4`.

However, from the assembly, we can know that there is no location `r13 - 4` and `i` is apparently at location `r13 + 4`.

Do I miss some calculation step? Anyone can explain the difference of `i`'s location between calculation from debugging information and in assembly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** The analysis in the question is correct and the discrepancy is a bug in one of the gcc components (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain is an obvious place to log one).

As it stands, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177403/1579636) is incorrect because it erroneously conflates the value of the stack pointer on evaluation of a location expression with the earlier value of the stack pointer on entry to the function.

As far as the DWARF is concerned, the location of `i` varies with the program counter.  Consider, for example, the text address `delay+0x18`.  At this point, the location of `i` is given by `DW_OP_fbreg(-12)`, i.e. 12 bytes below the frame base.  The frame base is given by the  parent `DW_TAG_subprogram`'s `DW_AT_frame_base` attribute which, in this case, is also dependent on the program counter:  for `delay+0x18` its expression is `DW_OP_breg13(8)`, i.e. `r13 + 8`.  Importantly, this calculation uses the **current** value of `r13`, i.e. the value of `r13` when the program counter is equal to `delay+0x18`.

Thus the DWARF asserts that, at `delay+0x18`, `i` is located at `r13 + 8 - 12`, i.e. 4 bytes below the bottom of the existing stack.  Inspection of the assembly shows that, at `delay+018`, `i` should be found 4 bytes **above** the bottom of the stack.  Therefore the DWARF is in error and whatever generated it is defective.

One can demonstrate the bug using `gdb` with a simple wrapper around the test case provided in the question:

```
$ cat delay.c
void delay(int num)
{
   volatile int i;
   for(i=0; i<num; i++);
}
$ gcc-4.6 -g -O1 -c delay.c
$ cat main.c
void delay(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    delay(3);
}
$ gcc-4.6 -o test main.c delay.o
$ gdb ./test
.
.
.
(gdb)
```

Set a breakpoint at `delay+0x18` and run to the second occurrence (where we expect `i` to be 1):

```
(gdb) break *delay+0x18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x103cc: file delay.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x000103cc in delay (num=3) at delay.c:4
4      for(i=0; i<num; i++);
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x000103cc in delay (num=3) at delay.c:4
4      for(i=0; i<num; i++);
(gdb)
```

We know from the disassembly that `i` is four bytes above the stack pointer.  Indeed, there it is:

```
(gdb) print *((int *)($r13 + 4))
$1 = 1
(gdb)
```

However, the bogus DWARF means that gdb looks in the wrong place:

```
(gdb) print i
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

As explained above, the DWARF is incorrectly giving the location of `i` at four bytes below the stack pointer.  There's a zero there, hence the reported value of `i`:

```
(gdb)  print *((int *)($r13 - 4))
$3 = 0
(gdb)
```

This isn't a coincidence.  A magic number written into this bogus location below the stack pointer reappears when `gdb` is asked to print `i`:

```
(gdb) set *((int *)($r13 - 4)) = 42
(gdb) print i
$6 = 42
(gdb)
```

Thus, at `delay+0x18`, **the DWARF incorrectly encodes the location of `i` as `r13 - 4` even though its true location is `r13 + 4`**.

One can go a step further by editing the compilation unit by hand and replacing `DW_OP_fbreg(-12)` (bytes `0x91 0x74`) with `DW_OP_fbreg(-4)` (bytes `0x91 0x7c`).  This gives

```
$ readelf --debug-dump=loc delay.modified.o 
Contents of the .debug_loc section:

Offset   Begin            End              Expression
00000000 00000000 00000004 (DW_OP_breg13 (r13): 0)
0000000c 00000004 00000038 (DW_OP_breg13 (r13): 8)
00000018 <End of list>
00000020 0000000c 00000020 (DW_OP_fbreg: -4)
0000002c 00000024 00000028 (DW_OP_reg3 (r3))
00000037 00000028 00000038 (DW_OP_fbreg: -4)
00000043 <End of list>

$
```

In other words, the DWARF has been corrected so that at, e.g., `delay+0x18` the location of `i` is given as `frame base - 4 = r13 + 8 - 4 = r13 + 4`, matching the assembly.  Repeating the gdb experiment with the corrected DWARF shows the expected value of `i` each time around the loop:

```
$ gcc-4.6 -o test.modified main.c delay.modified.o
$ gdb ./test.modified 
.
.
.
(gdb) break *delay+0x18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x103cc: file delay.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/test.modified 

Breakpoint 1, 0x000103cc in delay (num=3) at delay.c:4
4      for(i=0; i<num; i++);
(gdb) print i
$1 = 0
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x000103cc in delay (num=3) at delay.c:4
4      for(i=0; i<num; i++);
(gdb) print i
$2 = 1
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x000103cc in delay (num=3) at delay.c:4
4      for(i=0; i<num; i++);
(gdb) print i
$3 = 2
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 30954) exited with code 03]
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not agree with the OP's asm analysis:

```
00000000 <delay>:                         ; so far, let's suppose sp = sp(0) 
0:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8           ; sp = sp(0) - 8
4:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0               ; r3 = 0 
8:   e58d3004    str r3, [sp, #4]         ; store the value of r3 in (sp + 4)
c:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]         ; load (sp + 4) in r3
10:   e1500003    cmp r0, r3              ; compare r3 and r0  
14:   da000005    ble 30 <delay+0x30>     ; go to end of loop
18:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]        ; i is in r3, and it is being loaded from
                                          ; (sp + 4), that is, 
                                          ; sp(i) = sp(0) - 8 + 4 = sp(0) - 4
1c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1          ; r3 = r3 + 1, that is, increment i
20:   e58d3004    str r3, [sp, #4]        ; store i (which is in r3) in (sp + 4),
                                          ; being again sp(i) = sp(0) - 8 + 4 = \
                                          ; sp(0) - 4
24:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]        ; load sp + 4 in r3
28:   e1530000    cmp r3, r0              ; compare r3 and r0
2c:   bafffff9    blt 18 <delay+0x18>     ; go to init of loop
30:   e28dd008    add sp, sp, #8          ; sp = sp + 8
34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr                  ;
```

So `i` is located in `sp(0) - 4`, which matchs with the dwarf analysis (which says that `i` is being located in `0 + 8 - 12`)

Edit in order to add information regarding my DWARF analysis:

According to this line: `00000020 0000000c 00000020 (DW_OP_fbreg: -12)` , being DW_OP_fbreg :

> The DW_OP_fbreg operation provides a signed LEB128 offset from
>   the address specified by
>   the location description in the DW_AT_frame_base attribute of the
>   current function. (This is
>   typically a “stack pointer” register plus or minus some offset.
>   On more sophisticated systems
>   it might be a location list that adjusts the offset according to
>   changes in the stack pointer as
>   the PC changes.)

,the address is frame_base + offset, where:

- frame_base : is the stack pointer +/- some offset, and according to the previous line (`00000000 00000004 00000038 (DW_OP_breg13 (r13): 8)`), from 00000004 to 00000038, it has an offset of +8 (r13 is SP)
- offset: obviously it is -12

Given that, DWARF indicates that it is pointing to sp(0) + 8 - 12 = `sp(0) - 4`

Comment: According to the OP's analysis, the DWARF says that `i` is at `sp(0) - 12` but the asm shows that it is at `sp(0) - 4`.

Comment: @RobertHarris As far as I understood, the OP's analysis says that according to the asm, `i` is being located in the SP with an offset of +4 ([...is apparently at location `r13 + 4`...]), however the dwarf is reporting `i` as SP with an offset of -4 ([...the location of `i` is `r13 + 8 -12 = r13 - 4` ...]). IMO, the dwarf analysis makes sense (0 + 8 - 12, the offset is -4), but not the asm analysis. Most probably I am wrong, but I cannot see where the OP says that the dward reports SP - 12.

Comment: The DWARF expresses `i`'s location as an offset from the _frame base_.  E.g. at delay+0x18 it is 12 bytes below the **current** value of the frame base.  However, for this PC, the frame base is 8 bytes above the **current** value of r13;  in fact, for the OP's case, the frame base is a fixed value equal to the stack pointer on entry to the function.  Therefore, at delay+0x18, the DWARF gives the location of `i` as 12 bytes below the original value of r13, i.e. 4 bytes **below** the **current** value of r13.  The assembly shows that `i` is 4 bytes **above** the current value of r13.

Comment: Your own conclusion is incorrect: at, e.g., delay+0x18 the location of `i` is (the value of r13 at delay+0x18) + 8 - 12 = sp(0) - 12 = sp - 4.